# Webpack returns error in CI - TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'reflect-metadata'

Tags: azure, webpack, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I have a simple nodejs dictionary application that use webpack for client side module management and concatination of scripts. Everything works fine in my local machine. Now I am doing some experiments with CI in Azure. During this experiments with Azure's continous delivery options using CI from visualstudio.com, I have encounter the following error when executing webpack task (I am using the webpack task from the marketplace). Can anyone help me out?

The webpack build task specific log file says:

```
2017-07-31T13:44:16.2307812Z ##[section]Starting: webpack
2017-07-31T13:44:16.2307812Z ==============================================================================
2017-07-31T13:44:16.2307812Z Task         : webpack
2017-07-31T13:44:16.2307812Z Description  : bundle your assets, scripts, images, styles
2017-07-31T13:44:16.2307812Z Version      : 3.0.19
2017-07-31T13:44:16.2307812Z Author       : Dealogic
2017-07-31T13:44:16.2307812Z Help         : [More information](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dealogic.webpack-vsts-extension) [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/)
2017-07-31T13:44:16.2307812Z ==============================================================================
2017-07-31T13:44:16.4428024Z webpack
2017-07-31T13:44:16.4447837Z webpackConfigLocation: ./webpack.browser.config.js
2017-07-31T13:44:16.4447837Z treatErrorsAs: warnings
2017-07-31T13:44:16.4447837Z treatWarningsAs: warnings
2017-07-31T13:44:16.4447837Z workingFolder: d:\a\1\s
2017-07-31T13:44:16.4447837Z webpackModuleLocation: null
2017-07-31T13:44:16.4457843Z webpack module resolution started
2017-07-31T13:44:16.7987854Z webpack module resolution finished
2017-07-31T13:44:16.7987854Z webpack config resolution started
2017-07-31T13:44:16.7997851Z webpack config resolution finished
2017-07-31T13:44:16.7997851Z compilation of the webpack project is started
2017-07-31T13:44:17.3707894Z 
2017-07-31T13:44:17.3707894Z [at-loader] Using typescript@2.4.2 from typescript and "tsconfig.json" from d:\a\1\s\client\tsconfig.json.
2017-07-31T13:44:17.3707894Z 
2017-07-31T13:44:19.1378300Z 
2017-07-31T13:44:19.1378300Z [at-loader] Checking started in a separate process...
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5368391Z 
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5368391Z [at-loader] Checking finished with 1 errors
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5428397Z compilation of the webpack project is done
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5498387Z Hash: 1f80fddb56bf16ebb0f6
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5498387Z Version: webpack 3.4.1
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5498387Z Time: 2631ms
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5498387Z             Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5498387Z     app-bundle.js  146 kB       0  [emitted]  main
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5498387Z app-bundle.js.map  179 kB       0  [emitted]  main
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5498387Z    [4] ./node_modules/inversify/lib/annotation/decorator_utils.js 2.56 kB {0} [built]
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5498387Z    [5] ./node_modules/inversify/lib/utils/guid.js 352 bytes {0} [built]
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5498387Z    [7] ./node_modules/inversify/lib/inversify.js 1.93 kB {0} [built]
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5498387Z    [8] ./client/src/Dependency/DependencyIdentifiers.js 395 bytes {0} [built]
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5498387Z   [11] ./node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js 48 kB {0} [built]
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5498387Z   [14] ./node_modules/inversify/lib/syntax/constraint_helpers.js 1.48 kB {0} [built]
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5498387Z   [15] ./node_modules/inversify/lib/planning/metadata_reader.js 962 bytes {0} [built]
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5498387Z   [16] ./client/src/index.ts 1.29 kB {0} [built]
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5498387Z   [17] ./client/src/Dependency/DependencyManager.js 983 bytes {0} [built]
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5498387Z   [18] ./client/src/Services/WordFetcherImpl.js 2.18 kB {0} [built]
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5498387Z   [45] ./node_modules/inversify/lib/annotation/post_construct.js 722 bytes {0} [built]
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5498387Z   [46] ./node_modules/process/browser.js 5.42 kB {0} [built]
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5498387Z   [48] ./client/src/Utils/UriUtils.js 356 bytes {0} [built]
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5498387Z   [49] ./client/src/Services/OxfordHelper.js 1.29 kB {0} [built]
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5498387Z   [50] ./client/src/Services/DictionaryService.js 2.13 kB {0} [built]
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5498387Z     + 36 hidden modules
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5498387Z 
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5498387Z ERROR in [at-loader] TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'reflect-metadata'.
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5568407Z ##[warning]webpack partially succeeded
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5568407Z ##[warning]webpack: [at-loader] TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'reflect-metadata'.
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5568407Z webpack summary section markdown file creation is started
2017-07-31T13:44:19.5568407Z webpack sumamry section markdown file is created with the name 'd:\a\1\s\webpack.webpack.result.md'
2017-07-31T13:44:20.0895996Z ##[section]Finishing: webpack
```

Here is the dependencies fragment from the package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.5.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.0",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "inversify": "^4.2.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "request": "^2.81.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/async": "^2.0.40",
    "@types/compression": "0.0.33",
    "@types/express": "^4.0.36",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.53",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.14",
    "@types/request": "^2.0.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "jasmine": "^2.6.0",
    "jasmine-console-reporter": "^1.2.7",
    "typescript": "*",
    "typings": "^2.1.1",
    "webpack": "^3.0.0"
  }
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: I see that 'reflect-metadata' exists at dependencies. But node fails because it can not find it on disk. Try reinstall or install it. npm i reflect-metadata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was more of a MS TFS issue. When I changed Agent from "Hosted VS2017" to "Hosted Linux Preview" everything worked fine!

Not sure what is going on under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing reflect-metadata @types: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/reflect-metadata

```
npm i -D @types/reflect-metadata
```

Maybe you should add it on tsconfig.json, depends on your current configuration.